# Display list of entries from table on another sheet that match multiple IF criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file with two sheets and I'm trying to display information from the Master Sheet onto Sheet 2:

**Master Sheet**

```
|  ITEM  |  CRITERIA 1  |  CRITERIA 2  |
|  001   |  ABC         |  123         |
|  002   |  DEF         |  456         |
|  003   |  ABC         |  789         |
|  004   |  ABC         |  123         |
```

Right now I'm using the following formula to display all items from the Master Sheet that have a Criteria 1 of "ABC" (where "masterlist" is the name of the table containing the information):

```
=INDEX(masterlist[ITEM], SMALL(IF("ABC"=masterlist[CRITERIA 1], ROW(masterlist[ITEM])-1,""), ROW()-2))

|  ITEM  |  CRITERIA 1  |  CRITERIA 2  |
|  001   |  ABC         |  123         |
|  003   |  ABC         |  789         |
|  004   |  ABC         |  123         |
```

But I want to display all items that match both Criteria 1 of "ABC" ***and*** a Criteria 2 of "123".

I've been able to display and repeat only the *first* entry that matches both of those criteria using:

```
=INDEX(masterlist[ITEM],MATCH("ABC",masterlist[CRITERIA 1],0),MATCH("123",masterlist[CRITERIA 2],0))

|  ITEM  |  CRITERIA 1  |  CRITERIA 2  |
|  001   |  ABC         |  123         |
|  001   |  ABC         |  123         |
|  001   |  ABC         |  123         |
|  001   |  ABC         |  123         |
```

But I can't seem to loop through the data like I can in the first formula, no matter what I try. I've tried combining the two formulas every way I can think of.

Is there an easier way to do this? I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the second requirement to the first formula:

```
=INDEX(masterlist[ITEM], SMALL(IF(("ABC"=masterlist[CRITERIA 1])*(masterlist[CRITERIA 2]="123"), ROW(masterlist[ITEM])-1,""), ROW()-2))
```

Comment: I love you. It works. I've tried a similar formula, but I would always combine the two IF requirements with a comma (,) or I'd try using MATCH with an asterisk (*). Maybe that's where I went wrong?

Anyways, THANK YOU.